# Issue with options binding in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js `options binding on select-list`. I created an example fiddle:

http://jsbin.com/uzecaf/12/edit

But the problem is instead of showing value text on ui, [object object] is displayed on ui. What i am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

**Js Code**

```
function AuthorVM(){
  this.Name = ko.observable("bla-bla");
  this.books = ko.observableArray(
    [
      new BookVM('book-1', '1'),
      new BookVM('book-2', '2'),
      new BookVM('book-3', '3'),
      new BookVM('book-4', '4')
    ]
  );
}

function BookVM(name, id){
    this.Name = name;
    this.Id = id;
}

ko.applyBindings(new AuthorVM());
```

**MarkUp**

```
<label data-bind="text: Name"></label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<select data-bind="options: books, optionsText: Name">
</select>
```

Comment: copy in the code into your question so that people can see the what needed to change to make this work.

Comment: @sgtz I edited the question please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `select` binding is wrong, the [optionsText parameter](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) is a `string` so you need pass there a property name as a string.

Your binding should look like:

```
<select data-bind="options: books, optionsText: 'Name'">
```

See [Demo](http://jsbin.com/akiqak/1/edit).